# Notificações com Spring

Tags: java, spring, socket

como implementar um sistema de notificações que recebem em tempo real um contador de notificações exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida e que quando for inserido lá no banco mais uma linha e passe de 4 para 5 se atualizando na mesma sessão o mais rápido possível ? como fazer isso ? desde já , agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicar em detalhes, passo-a-passo, como desenvolver o sistema é algo fora de escopo. Mas basicamente você pode usar o Spring Boot para facilitar o trabalho pesado.

A arquitetura é simples:

- O servidor precisa disponibilizar um canal via WebSockets para que o cliente (navegador) possa receber atualizações.
- A página deve ter um JavaScript que se inscreva para receber atualizações (mensagens) do servidor.

[Neste tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) você encontra um exemplo simples. Por cima de WebSockets, ele usa uma [biblioteca](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/) baseada no protocolo STOMP para comunicação via texto, mais especificamente, JSON.

## Cliente

O código no cliente para conectar, desconectar, enviar e recebermensagens fica assim:

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
}

function disconnect() {
    if (stompClient != null) {
        stompClient.disconnect();
    }
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Disconnected");
}

function sendName() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name }));
}
```

A função `showGreeting` chamada no primeiro método seria a responsável por exibir a mensagem recebida.

## Servidor

Você pode criar um controller para receber e retornar mensagens:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
}
```

Infelizmente, neste exemplo do tutorial, ele apenas manda uma mensagem e finaliza.

Já [neste outro tutorial](http://mpas.github.io/blog/2015/06/16/adding-websocket/stomp-support-to-a-spring-boot-application/) você encontra um exemplo de como publicar mensagens no canal se forma assíncrona (em qualquer momento):

```
@Service
public class ScheduleTask {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    // this will send a message to an endpoint on which a client can subscribe
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void trigger() {
        // sends the message to /topic/message
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/message", "Date: " + new Date());
    }

}
```

A configuração (conforme o segundo tutorial) é assim:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        // the endpoint for websocket connections
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        // use the /topic prefix for outgoing WebSocket communication
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");

        // use the /app prefix for others
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

## Banco de dados

Os exemplos acima não consideram bancos de dados. Infelizmente, receber eventos do banco de dados ou fazer *polling* (verificação contínua) em geral não são possíveis ou mesmo recomendados.

O ideal é que seu sistema contenha alguma API de notificação, onde cada nova mensagem gere uma notificação que vá para uma fila. Eventualmente algum código assíncrono pode capturar essa mensagem e publicar no canal correto, como no exemplo acima onde o agendador publica a data no canal.

Claro que você pode implementar isso de forma síncrona, mas geralmente isso vai gerar impactos muito negativos na performance, por isso aplicações de verdade não fazem isso.

Comment: Já estou usando o spring boot :D obrigado pelo retorno :)

Comment: esse tipo de implementação serve pra qualquer tipo de dado ? por exemplo tenho um servidor e dois clientes. e os clientes são jogadores é um jogo , um cliente se "anda" e o outro cliente "ver"  é de fato a mesma ideia de implementação?

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto A implementação de exemplo transmite informações no formato JSON. Você pode adaptar a classe Greeting do tutorial para conter qualquer dado que desejar ou mesmo transmitir em outro formato. A implementação para um jogo pode usar o mesmo princípio, onde a estrutura de dados deve transmitir os movimentos do outro jogador. Nesse caso, sugiro usar um tópico diferente por jogador, de forma que você possa enviar mensagens para cada um individualmente. Só que se o jogo for em tempo real, provavelmente vai ser um desafio porque você deve considerar a latência da comunicação.

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto Achei um artigo interessante que conta como um jogo em tempo real foi feito usando websockets com uma latência de no máximo 200 milissegundos: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket

Comment: Muito bom o artigo. Agradeço o retorno.